# Bootstrap - Progress bars in form-control

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

i have a question, how can i put a bootstrap progress bar into a form control? I'm trying to do a password strength indicator with a progress bar, but when i put the progressbar into the form control it always shows as full, even though the value of the bar is 0%;

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c31B.png)

Code(html):

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"></span></span>
    <input id="pass" type="password" name="password" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <div class="progress-bar form-control">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple: you ***don't*** put a `.progress-bar` inside a `.form-control`.

You need to pay more attention to Bootstrap markup. (*Or to the CSS behind it.*)

First of all, you shouldn't put anything else inside `.input-group`s, other than one single `<input>` with the class of `.form-control` and `.input-group-addon`s before or after the `input`.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

If you want to place a *progress bar*, again, you need to pay attention to the Bootstrap markup. You have wrap it in a `.progress` wrapper:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could combine the two and keep them together by wrapping them in a `.form-group`. So your initial markup should be replaced by:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"></span></span>
    <input id="pass" type="password" name="password" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
      <span class="sr-only">Password security 0%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll pay more attention in the future.

Comment: For this, i'll have to put the progress bar into the input group though, because i want it to be under the password input.

Comment: I replaced the last code snippet with the complete markup you should use instead of your initial `<div class="input-group">` (the one you posted).